# How to deal with coords like 50°32'20.548\\\"N"?

Tags: java, android, maps

I want to implement a map in my Android project. I have the map, coords and all methods ready, but I found out that I don't know what to do with this coords format I received:

50°32'20.548\\"N"

Android Studio expects double format like this: -33.852, 151.211
......and I don't have any idea how to convert it. Has anyone dealt with a similar problem and can help me please?

Thank you :)

The coords I have to work with (can't change them):

```
{
  "monumentid1": {
    "name": "Bečov nad Teplou - Zámek",
    "gpsx": "50°5'8.145\\\"N",
    "gpsy": "12°50'23.468\\\"E"
  },
  "monumentid2": {
    "name": "Benešov nad Ploučnicí - Zámek ",
    "gpsx": "50°44'32.727\\\"N",
    "gpsy": "14°18'39.412\\\"E"
  },
  "monumentid3": {
    "name": "Bezděz - Hrad",
    "gpsx": "50°32'20.548\\\"N",
    "gpsy": "14°43'11.607\\\"E"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Location`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#convert(java.lang.String)) class has a static method to perform DMS string conversion (to double) - but first your string needs to be adjusted to match the acceptable format of 'DD:MM:SS.SSSS'.  Once converted the sign needs to adjusted for hemisphere:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       // The triple backslash is data author's attempt to escape the double-quote.
       String s = "50°32'20.548\\\"N";

       // Get rid of any residual backslashes
       s = s.replace("\\","");

       // split string into constituent parts using apparent separators
       String[] dms = s.split("[°'\"]");

       // form 'newS' which complies with Location.FORMAT_SECONDS
       String newS = dms[0]+":"+dms[1]+":"+dms[2];

       // and grab hemisphere (to implement sign)
       String hemi = dms[3];

       double coord = Location.convert(newS);
       if (hemi.compareTo("W") == 0 || hemi.compareTo("S") == 0) {
           coord = -coord;
       }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

well 1 degree is 60 minutes and 1 minute is 60 seconds...

e.g.

50°30' is the same as 50.5

Answer (score 0):

You should write a function which takes in a String and converts those coordinates into numbers which you can then work with.